# c++ file handling problem

Tags: c++, linux

hi everybody out there i need help from u in  file handling
I'm using Ubuntu as my operating system

now my c++ code has a line `remove("/home/manish.yadav/Desktop/ram.txt");`
 last time i ran this command in C code it remove my operating system

now I'm not sure to use it or not ?
can anyone tell me proper syntax of this command so that i can use it in my code ?
is there any other way to remove files  in c++ by using programs? how to do this?
how delete file using c++ program ?

Comment: I'll bet fairly good money that remove("/home/manish.yadav/Desktop/ram.txt"); didn't actually remove your operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into [the reference page for std::remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/) on how to use it to remove files.

Concerning your OS, std::remove doesn't randomly kill OSs. Last time I tried it, the function worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

try it !

```
unlink("/home/manish.yadav/Desktop/ram.txt");
```

Comment: unlink and remove are behaving the same way for files.

Answer (score 1):

"last time i ran this command in C code it remove my operating system".

No, it didn't. Something else did, and we have no crystal ball to guess what that was.